# Unit test Karma -Unknown provider

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, x-editable

I'm writing unit tests for my project built on Angularjs with Karma-jasmine. I'm using [x-editable library](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/) in my app.

I'm trying to unit test a controller which depends on the x-editable library.
But I'm facing the error below :

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: editableThemesProvider <- edit ableThemes
```

I have already added the path of x-editable my in Karma config file :

```
files:[ 
    ...... 
    { pattern: '../../libs/angular/angular-xeditable/dist/js/xeditable.min.js', watched: false },
     ........ 
    ]
```

Below the spec file :

```
beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, $rootScope, $localStorage, _editableThemes_, _editableOptions_) {
 localStorage = $localStorage;
 $controller = _$controller_;
 editThemes = _editableThemes_;
 editOptions = _editableOptions_;
 scope = $rootScope.$new();
 leaderboardCtrl = $controller('LeaderboardCtrl', {
  $scope: scope,
  $modal : modal,
  $q: q,
  editableOptions: editOptions,
  editableThemes: editThemes,
  $localStorage: localStorage,
  LeaderBoardService : leaderboardService
});
}));
```

And this is my **controller file** :

```
(function() {
'use strict';
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('LeaderboardCtrl', leaderboardCtrl);

leaderboardCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$q',  '$modal', '$localStorage', 'editableOptions', 'editableThemes', 'LeaderBoardService'];

function leaderboardCtrl  ( $scope,   $q,  $modal,   $localStorage,   editableOptions,   editableThemes,   LeaderBoardService) {
  var event_ID = $localStorage.currentEventId;
  editableThemes.bs3.inputClass = 'input-sm';
  editableThemes.bs3.buttonsClass = 'btn-sm';
  editableOptions.theme = 'bs3';
```

What am I doing wrong? did i missed something?

Comment: Can you show the module definition for `leaderboardCtrl`?

Comment: @Puigcerber check! I updated the question

Comment: Did you add `'xeditable'` to the dependencies of your `'app'` module?

Comment: yeah it injected automatically because i'm using oc.lazyload in my app, the app works correctally but unit tests fail.